# SQLite performance on large tables

Tags: performance, sqlite

EDIT: My fault here was very basic: I did not use a PRIMARY KEY for indexing. To make this thread a bit more useful I added performance data for searching my table with and without indexing for performance comparison.

I'm using sqlite3 in python in an application running both under windows and linux. My database file is currently in the range of 700 MB.

I recognized one special performance issue regarding the number of entries in my largest table. It consists of 10 columns being integer and float numbers and one varchar.

The table has 1.6 Mio rows. For that size each SELECT or UPDATE command takes 327ms. That is by far too long for my application, since it mainly waits on sqlite now.

I recognized, that performance drastically increases with table size dropping. I found:

- 1.6M entries 327 ms w/o indexing => 29.7 ms with indexing
- 670k entries 149 ms w/o indexing => 28.8 ms with indexing
- 280k entries 71 ms w/o indexing => 28.5 ms with indexing
- 147k entries 44 ms w/o indexing => 28.0 ms with indexing
- 19k entries 25 ms w/o indexing => 25.0 ms with indexing

CONCLUSION: using indexing search times almost stay constant while seach times w/o indexing almost linearily rise with table size. Only for very small tables the difference is negligible.

Comment: What is your schema? What are your queries? Are you using indexes?

Comment: If you have found a solution to your own problem, please accept an answer or add your own. Please do not edit your question with the answer.

Answer (score 6):

When query time scales linearly with table size, your queries are probably doing a full table scan, meaning they have to read all the rows in the table. This generally means they're not [using indexes](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp).

We can't tell you what you should index without seeing your schema and queries. You can see what your query is doing by putting [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) in front of it like `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM foo`. If you see "SCAN TABLE" that's a full table scan. if you see "USING INDEX" that's using indexes.

Comment: That's it. Sorry, that was quite a basic problem of DB knowhow. I just was not searching using my index, which in return means I need to chose a more appropriate index for my table.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that each column in the WHERE (and JOIN, if used) clause of your SELECT and UPDATE appears in an index, or is part of the primary key of your table.

Note also that the performance improvement due to index is tied to the constant size of the query result. If the number of query results grows linearly with table size, the effect of the index gets limited because the resulting data amount transfered back to application can not be meaningfully reduced. In this case you may need to make deeper performance analysis.

Comment: Also the JOIN fields should be indexed.

Comment: True. I have forgotten them.